# In Python, how do you create a 2D list from a file and assign a type to each item in each sublist?

Tags: python, list, types, 2d

Sorry if that's an awkward title. Here's what I want to do:

1. Read a txt file that on each line contains: country name, area, population
2. Each line turns into a sublist within a main list
3. Each sublist needs to retain the type of variable, so: string,float,int for each sublist

A sample of what would be a long output is:

```
[['Afghanistan', '647500.0', '25500100'], ['Albania', '28748.0', '2821977'], ['Algeria', '2381740.0', '38700000'], ['American Samoa', '199.0', '55519'], ['Andorra', '468.0', '76246']
```

etc... and python needs to know the type of each variable, for example if i wanted to create a new function that sorts all floats in the list.

Here's what I have now, but it only returns each line as a sublist, and I believe doesn't know the type if I wanted to use this 2d list for new functions.

```
def Countries(filename):
f = open(filename)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
myList = []
for line in lines:
    myList.append(line.strip().split(','))
return myList
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
def Countries(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    myList = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        line_data = line.split(",")
        myList.append(line_data)
    return myList
```

But, if it's a .txt file I think it's only going to be returning strings. So, you'd have to convert types.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how do you convert types? That's what I'm hung up on. I'm not sure how to convert while putting the items in the sublists, or if i have to do this after.

Comment: If you know for **absolute** certain that each list will be [string, float, int], under line_data you could add conversion line something like:

line_data = [line_data[0], float(line_data[1]), int(line_data[2])]

Otherwise, you might need to use something with the typeCheck function posted by R Nar below to be on the safe side.

Comment: My man! Yeah, it's for absolute certain, so it'll work this way. Thank you so much, I'm starting to understand the concept better.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem you have is that `f.readlines()` reads everything as a string. you can then map each item in your sublist through a type checker like this:

```
def typeCheck(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except:
            return s
```

will try to explicitly cast your parameter as an 'int', then a 'float', then just leave it as is. it is this order because all things that can be cast as a 'int' can also be cast as a 'float' but not the other way around so you want to check for the `int` first (ie, `'123.1'` will raise an error for `int('123.1')` but not `float('123.1')`)

you can then append the mapped list like this:

```
for line in lines:
    myList.append(list(map(typeCheck,line.strip().split(',')))
```

and your values that can be converted to floats and int will be converted.

EXAMPLE:

```
>>> def typeCheck(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except:
            return s


>>> l = [['Afghanistan', '647500.0', '25500100'], ['Albania', '28748.0', '2821977'], ['Algeria', '2381740.0', '38700000'], ['American Samoa', '199.0', '55519'], ['Andorra', '468.0', '76246']]
>>> for i in l: print(list(map(typeCheck,i)))

['Afghanistan', 647500.0, 25500100]
['Albania', 28748.0, 2821977]
['Algeria', 2381740.0, 38700000]
['American Samoa', 199.0, 55519]
['Andorra', 468.0, 76246]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i'm deciding on whether to use yours or Jeremy's... both so the trick :)